# Why does my PHP filtering SQL data only work if all filters are used?

Tags: php, arrays, filter

My $data array is only updated when all three filters are used or none of them are. The POST methods are coming from an HTML dropdown so they are single strings.

```
$data = [];

    $jobFilter = isset($_POST['jobsToFilter']) ? $_POST['jobsToFilter'] : null;
    $departmentFilter = isset($_POST['departmentsToFilter']) ? $_POST['departmentsToFilter'] : null;
    $locationFilter = isset($_POST['locationsToFilter']) ? $_POST['locationsToFilter'] : null;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      if (($jobFilter === null || $row['jobTitle'] === $jobFilter) &&

          ($departmentFilter === null || $row['department'] === $departmentFilter) &&

          ($locationFilter === null || $row['location'] === $locationFilter)) {

            array_push($data, $row);
      }
```

Am I misunderstanding the logic of the code? If the filter is not Null and that value matches the filter, add it to $data. However, $data is only updated when none or all of them are in use.

Comment: Just as an aside, it seems very odd (and not really very efficient) to do this in PHP rather than SQL

Comment: On the other hand, doing the dynamic filtering in PHP means it's not vulnerable to SQL injection, which virtually every PHP application written by novices is.

Comment: Demo: https://3v4l.org/HIssf - looks fine to me. Maybe those other filters _are_ set but are perhaps empty strings or something (because that would cause the behaviour you're describing - demo: https://3v4l.org/kOJW8)? Do a test with `var_dump($_POST);` to see what's really being submitted

Answer (score 1):

Where are your $_POST values coming from - text input fields, presumably ...?

Text input fields always cause an entry in the form submission data set, even if they are left empty - the corresponding $_POST entry will simply contain an empty string then. But that means, `isset($_POST['...'])` is still true then for that field - so you are *not* setting `$jobFilter` to `null` if the user left that field blank, it will be set to an empty string.

```
($jobFilter === null || $row['jobTitle'] === $jobFilter)
```

The first part is not true now - empty string and `null` are not *identical* - and so this whole condition can only be true now for records, where the `jobTitle` *also* contained just an empty string.

If you do not need to handle `0` as a user input, then you could just replace `isset` with `empty`. If `0` needs to be a valid input, then you better stick with `isset`, and add an explicit check that the value is not an empty string.